# Using df.apply on a function with multiple inputs to generate multiple outputs

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
initial year0 year1
0       0     12
1       1     13
2       2     14
3       3     15
```

Note that the number of year columns year0, year1... (year_count) is completely variable but will be constant throughout this code

I first wanted to apply a function to each of the 'year' columns to generate 'mod' columns like so

```
def mod(year, scalar):
    return (year * scalar)

s = 5
year_count = 2
# Generate new columns
df[[f"mod{y}" for y in range (year_count)]] = df[[f"year{y}" for y in range(year_count)]].apply(mod, scalar=s)  

initial year0 year1 mod0 mod1
0       0     12    0   60
1       1     13    5   65
2       2     14    10  70
3       3     15    15  75
```

All good so far. The problem is that I now want to apply another function to both the year column and its corresponding mod column to generate another set of val columns, so something like

```
def sum_and_scale(year_col, mod_col, scale):
    return (year_col + mod_col) * scale
```

Then I apply this to each of the columns (year0, mod0), (year1, mod1) etc to generate the next tranche of columns.

With scale = 10 I should end up with

```
initial year0 year1 mod0 mod1 val0 val1
0       0     12    0    60   0    720
1       1     13    5    65   60   780
2       2     14    10   70   120  840
3       3     15    15   75   180  900
```

This is where I'm stuck - I don't know how to put two existing df columns together in a function with the same structure as in the first example, and if I do something like

```
df[['val0', 'val1']] = df['col1', 'col2'].apply(lambda x: sum_and_scale('mod0', 'mod1', scale=10))
```

I don't know how to generalise this to have arbitrary inputs and outputs and also apply the constant scale parameter. (I know the last piece of won't work but it's the other avenue to a solution I've seen)

The reason I'm asking is because I believe the loop that I currently have working is creating performance issues with the number of columns and the length of each column.

Thanks

Comment: Is `sum_and_scale` your actual function or is it just a mockup?

Comment: It's a mockup, the minimum that I think is needed to get the actual function working which is a good deal more complicated

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, it's better with a simple `for` loop:

```
for i in range(2):
    df[f'val{i}'] = sum_and_scale(df[f'year{i}'], df[f'mod{i}'], scale=10)
```

Comment: I should have mentioned - the reason I'm asking is because I believe the loop is creating performance issues with the number of columns and the length of each column.

Comment: You have a minimal loop here in this situation so it wouldn’t be too bad. The function is still vectorized for each column. That said, `apply` itself is essentially a loop too.